# php banner caching suggestion

Tags: php, caching, banner

We serve several high load sites, and so far we came with this code for caching remote banners that support some basic local banner rotation. It should be fairly easy for all to understand, what I would like to hear from you about the possible improvement or suggestions on this code.
Here it is...

```
        $cachetime = 6 * 60 * 60; // 6 hours
        $bannercache = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/banner-".$bpos.".txt";

            // Serve from the cache if it is younger than $cachetime

            if (file_exists($bannercache) && (time() - $cachetime
             < filemtime($bannercache)))
            {

                    // if it's ok don't update from remote

            } else {

                    // if cache is old, update from remote


                    $bannercachecontent = @file_get_contents('ADSERVER.com/showad.php?category='.$adcat.'&dimensions='.$dimensions);

                    if ($bannercachecontent === FALSE) {

                        // on error, just update local time, so that it's not pulled again in case of remote mysql overload

                        $fb = @fopen($bannercache, 'a+');
                        fwrite($fb, "\n<!-- Changed date on ".date('jS F Y H:i', filemtime($cachefile))."-->\n");
                        fclose($fb);

                    } else {

                        // if it's ok, save new local file

                        $fb = @fopen($bannercache, 'w');
                        fwrite($fb, $bannercachecontent);
                        fwrite($fb, "\n<!-- Cached ".date('jS F Y H:i', filemtime($cachefile))."-->\n");
                        fclose($fb);
                    }



            }



        $fhm = file_get_contents($bannercache);



        $fhmpos = strpos($fhm, '-----#####-----'); // check if it needs to be exploded for rotation
        if ($fhmpos === false) {

            echo $fhm;

        } else {

            $fhmpicks = explode("-----#####-----", $fhm);


        foreach ($fhmpicks as $fhmkey => $fhmvalue)
        {
            if (trim($fhmpicks[$fhmkey]) == '')
            {
                unset($fhmpicks[$fhmkey]);
            }
        }


            $fhmpick = array_rand($fhmpicks,1);

            echo $fhmpicks[$fhmpick]; // show only one banner

        }
```

Comment: btw: you could fix up your source a bit: there is a lot of whitespace that isn't really good for reading in a post here, and the whole rotation-scheme (the part follwing `$fhmpos` I guess) isn't relevant at all.

Answer (score 0):

Don't let your clients update your banners. You will always have 1 user that has to do this, and that isn't necessary:

Instead: let you clients always load the local image, and run a **background process** (cron, with a manual override if you want to pull the image NOW) that fetches the right image(s).

The code would be fairly simple:

your client does: `$yourImage= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/banner-".$bpos.".txt";`

and your update-script can just `cURL` the right image.

Comment: hi Nanne, thanks for reply on this matter... however we have over 50 websites using this technique and the banner sizes vary... we would need a pretty advanced cron for that :-)